# Best Interface for an Auction Website MVC

Tags: usability, website-design, interaction-design, navigation, web-app

I am designing an auction website using ASP.NET MVC. I am trying to get a home layout that is both appealing and functional for the users.

**Here is my basic site as I have it now:**
[image: old website]

**And here is what my "vision" right now is:**
[image: vision of website]

Obviously the vision would look more clean, (I made it in ms paint lol)

I would like the left nav bar to be collapsible because I think this would be the most user friendly and I want it to show up on every page. The right nav bar I am thinking should also be collapsible because when a user first signs in and hasn't added anything to their "watch" list, then nothing will be displayed there anyway.

I put the deals section since my customer told me that a lot of times the electronics and other items are won for really good deals, they want the users to get good deals but not great deals. So I would have a method to calculate the "deals" and display the best ones accordingly.

Im thinking maybe getting rid of the FAQ under the deals and just changing the About on the top nav bar to FAQ. Otherwise maybe just making "My Bids" a clickable link/button that takes them to the items they bid on.

> If you were a user, would you like the vision layout? Is there too much going on? Any improvements? Please let me know as I need another opinion. Thank you.

Comment: Hello again! Unfortunately, unlike your previous questions, this one doesn't quite fit the site very well. If you have a specific question about a particular aspect of your UI or information architecture, then that would be welcome here, but as it stands, this question reads a lot like a site review request which is considered [off-topic](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1528/lets-document-that-site-reviews-are-off-topic) here. Feel free to [edit] if you'd like to focus your question!